npm run babel not creating css files
I'm running this command in package.json:
"babel": "babel src/lib -d build"

This is the full package.json file:
{
      "name": "react-bullet-components",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "main": "dist/index.js",
      "module": "dist/index.js",
      "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
      "files": [ "dist", "README.md"],
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
        "cra-template": "1.2.0",
        "react": "^19.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^19.0.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "babel": "babel src/lib -d build"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.26.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
        "web-vitals": "^4.2.4"
      }
}

The files like the .js files are generated when calling this command:
npm run babel

The babel.config.json:
        {
            "presets":[
                [
                    "@babel/env",
                    {
                        "targets":{
                            "edge": "17",
                            "firefox": "60",
                            "chrome": "67",
                            "safari": "11.1"
                        },
                        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                        "corejs": "3.6.5"
                    }
                ],
                "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
        }

But my styles.css is not generated - how do I do this?
